# Cuke4nuke: Is it missing the support for different languages?

Tags: c#, .net, cucumber

I'm using the version 0.3.1 of Cuke4Nuke and I'm having problems defining my feature-files with an other language than English. Googling didn't bring any solutions, so my question is simple: Does Cuke4Nuke support defining the features in other languages than English?

I've tried to use the examples from the GitHub's Cucumber repository. Here's an example of feature which doesn't work:

```
# language: no
Egenskap: Summering
  For å unngå at firmaet går konkurs
  Må regnskapsførerere bruke en regnemaskin for å legge sammen tall

Scenario: to tall
  Gitt at jeg har tastet inn 5
  Og at jeg har tastet inn 7
  Når jeg summerer
  Så skal resultatet være 12
```

When compiled and run through Cuke4Nuke the error message is like following:

> Cuke4Nuke
>   C:_work\myProject\Tests\Integration.Tests\bin\Debug\Integration.Tests.dll
>   C:_work\myProject\Tests\Integration.Tests\features
>   -q  C:/_work/myProject/Tests/Integration.Tests/features/summering.feature:
>   Lexing error on line 2: 'Egenskap:
>   Summering'. See
>   http://wiki.github.com/aslakhellesoy/gherkin/lexingerror
>   for more information.
>   (Gherkin::Lexer::LexingError)
>   C:/_work/tools/Ruby186/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gherkin-2.2.4-x86-mingw32/lib/gherkin/lexer/i18n_lexer.rb:22:in
>   `scan'
>   C:/_work/tools/Ruby186/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gherkin-2.2.4-x86-mingw32/lib/gherkin/lexer/i18n_lexer.rb:22:in`
>   scan'
>   C:/_work/tools/Ruby186/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gherkin-2.2.4-x86-mingw32/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:31:in
>   `parse'
>   C:/_work/tools/Ruby186/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.9.0/bin/../lib/cucumber/feature_file.rb:35:in`
>   parse'
>   C:/_work/tools/Ruby186/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.9.0/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:28:in
>   `load'
>   C:/_work/tools/Ruby186/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.9.0/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:26:in`
>   each'
>   C:/_work/tools/Ruby186/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.9.0/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:26:in
>   `load'
>   C:/_work/tools/Ruby186/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.9.0/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:14:in`
>   features'
>   C:/_work/tools/Ruby186/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.9.0/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:179:in
>   `features'
>   C:/_work/tools/Ruby186/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.9.0/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:32:in`
>   run!'
>   C:/_work/tools/Ruby186/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.9.0/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:54:in
>   `execute!'
>   C:/_work/tools/Ruby186/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.9.0/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:29:in`
>   execute'
>   C:/_work/tools/Ruby186/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.9.0/bin/cucumber:8 C:/_work/tools/Ruby186/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'`load'

It seems that cuke4nuke (or Cucumber?) is skipping the # language -declaration completely. For example the following feature-works when it shouldn't.

```
# language: fi
Feature: Addition
In order to avoid silly mistakes
As a math idiot 
I want to be told the sum of two numbers

Scenario Outline: Add two numbers
Given I have entered <input_1> into the calculator
And I have entered <input_2> into the calculator
When I press <button>
hen the result should be <output> on the screen

Examples:
| input_1 | input_2 | button | output |
| 20      | 30      | add    | 50     |
| 2       | 5       | add    | 7      |
| 0       | 40      | add    | 40     |
```

Any ideas how could I make the Cucumber and Cuke4Nuke to notice the language -declaration? My Ruby is of version 1.86 and Cucumber is v. 0.9.

Comment: Are you aware of SpecFlow (www.specflow.org). It uses the same Gherkin Parser as Cucumber but runs natively on .NET. (Disclaimer: I am a committer of SpecFlow.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I eventually moved to SpecFlow and I've been using it happily since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an error on the Cucumber/Gherkin side, before anything goes to Cuke4Nuke. The language declaration is only handled on the Cucumber side. By the time the step details get to Cuke4Nuke, the keywords are gone. You're likely to get more help on the cukes group (groups.google.com/group/cukes/); I think the Cucumber developers are more active there.

That said, Cuke4Nuke doesn't handle languages yet. You'd still have to use Given/When/Then attributes on your step definitions rather than Gitt/Når/Så, and string conversions for step definition arguments won't use the correct culture, which may cause you problems. The next Cuke4Nuke release will include language support. The i18n attributes are already in the latest source, and I'm working on the culture stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I downloaded, build and installed the latest version of Cuke4Nuke from the GitHub and tried to run the included language-example but I'm getting the same error on that one. So it seems that the issue is on Cucumber's side like you mentioned. I've tested this now on two different computers and they both share the same problem, though they both are Win x64 machines.